# Slack uses too much browser storage (two orders of magnitude more than the next website). Why, and how can I limit it?

Tags: firefox, slack

I'm using slack in the browser. When looking at the application storage in firefox, I found that its storage requirements seem to be disproportionate compared to other websites:

[image: screenshot of "manage cookies and site data" table in firefox]

I'm wondering why it needs to store so much, and if I can limit the storage. Total storage across all websites is around ~1.13 GB so almost *all* of the website storage in firefox is slack.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that Slack is _not_ a website. It’s an application. I doubt you could have a decent user experience without caching everything including the GIFs that are spammed in channels.

Comment: Just for comparison: Microsoft Teams, which I sometimes use in Edge, has ~700 MiB cached.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known problem, dating from many years.
The used local storage will also multiply proportionately to your number
of teams.

One advice is to use the desktop version of Slack, although it is
basically only a wrapper around the Chrome browser, so its utility
is doubtful.
The Slack team did make 5 years ago an effort for
[Reducing Slack’s memory footprint](https://slack.engineering/reducing-slacks-memory-footprint/),
but this is useful only when you have teams that you haven’t
looked at in a while.

Basically, you can release this local storage in Firefox
*Settings > Privacy & Security > Manage Data...*
However, from all reports this is very temporary and may even cause
problems.

I think that, finally, this problem is one that you have to live with
if you wish to use Slack.

Comment: The article you link to is about RAM use, not about cache memory.

Comment: @DanielB: I know, but they did try to make their app somewhat more efficient, although their efforts don't look very impressive. This is partially the reason that I'm pessimistic about any possible improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to the Slack domain but perhaps helpful to know that you can constrain Firefox's total cache usage using this method:

1. In a new tab, type or paste `about:config` in the address bar and press Enter/Return. Click the button accepting the risk.
2. In the search box above the list, type or paste `cache.d` and pause while the list is filtered
3. Double-click the `browser.cache.disk.smart_size.enabled` preference to switch the value from true to false -- this is necessary to override the size, otherwise Firefox will enlarge it again in a day or two
4. Double-click the `browser.cache.disk.capacity` preference to display a dialog where you can edit the size, then click OK -- if this number is 7 digits, for example, 1000000, that is 1 gigabyte; if this number is 6 digits, for example, 500000, that is 500 megabytes.

Source: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1271481